# How-to Resume slide show after hyperlink ends

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide deck from which I hyperlink to other presentations (also PowerPoint). This all works smoothly.

When the hyperlinked presentation completes I get a message box where I have to click on "Resume Slide Show" to exit back to the initial PowerPoint slideshow.

Is there any way to get rid of this so that when the second slideshow ends it automatically goes back into the initial slideshow ?

I'm working with PowerPoint 2010 & 2013.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to automatically click the button of "Resume Slide Show",
then it is easy enough to have a [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
script that will watch for it and automatically do the click.
Let me know if you want to go this route and I will help with the script.

If you want to combine the presentation with others seamlessly so they
seem to be one presentation, you will find a detailed tutorial for that in the article
[Linking PowerPoint Presentations Together Seamlessly](https://www.awesomebackgrounds.com/powerpointlinking.htm).

Comment: Usually you only get that prompt when you've somehow dropped out of slideshow mode. Are you doing something that might cause that to happen?